# Please explain me about the grammar usage of this sentence ."It's the possibility of having a dream come true that makes life interesting"

Tags: grammar

It's the possibility of having a dream that makes life interesting.

Why do they use such a strange structure here?

Comment: What is it about its grammar that you don't understand? This is a pretty straightforward type of sentence, is it the article (the) in front of "possibility" but not appearing with "life" that makes you confused?

Comment: You need to explain why the sentence is giving you problems otherwise the question will likely be closed for being either too broad, unclear or for lack of effort/research. P.S Don't wait until the question is put on hold, often it's too late to get it fixed.

Comment: Why do you think that the structure is "strange"?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is an *emphatic* statement with introductory ***IT***.

Instead of the simple sentence
 "The possibility of having a dream makes life interesting"

we use this emphatic sentence with the meaning

"***Only*** the possibility of having a dream makes life interesting"

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it)

"***IT*** is often used to shift emphasis to a part of a statement other than the subject:

// it was in this city that the treaty was signed."